# Strange behaviour of Azure MySQL PaaS with regards to user@host

Tags: mysql, azure

When creating a PaaS MySQL server on Azure, one has to give the server a name (e.g. "mymysql") and provide a username and password for the admin user, for example "myadmin".

When trying to connect using MySQL workbench, one is supposed to use

```
myadmin@mysql
```

as the username.

This works fine when I try that from a VM in Azure. I can connect using MySQL workbench. Interesting enough, looking at the users list, I will find an entry

```
  myadmin@%
```

in there. I.e. theoretically, user myadmin from any host should be allowed to connect. Yet it does not work leaving the host portion out, i.e. I cannot connect using just "myadmin".

Now I an trying the very same from a client connected from a point-to-site-VPN.

I put

```
myadmin@mysql
```

in my connection string. But I will receive an error message saying

```
  myadmin@1.2.3.4 (IP address of VPN client)
```

is not allowed to connect, using password: YES

What's going on here?

Comment: Did you whitelist any IP addresses for your MySQL firewall config? Can you try adding the 'IP address of VPN client' to your firewall settings to allow connections. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/concepts-firewall-rules

Comment: This is a test to see if a connection is successful. If not, possibly a routing issue but need to understand if the firewall config is the issue. Thanks!